# How to get last access time of application in WebSphere Liberty Server 19.0.0.11

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

Am developing application in Java 8, JSF, Maven. Build application as war and deploying it in WebSphere Liberty Server 19.0.0.11. I got requirement to get application last access time.? Is there any way to get this detail.?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you consider 'application last access time' to be?

Comment: Example : After deployed application in server, User 1: Accessing application by entering URL in browser (even ajax request) or last request time is : 17-Feb-2020 16:50. User 2: last request time is 20-Feb-2020 14:25. Here I need last access time as 20-Feb-2020 14:25. So I need time that last request handled by application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do that is by watching the `vendor_servlet_request_total` metric (provided by the mpMetrics-2.x feature).  There is a separately labeled time series for each servlet (a time series is a sequence of metric values in chronological order) -- by periodically polling the `/metrics` endpoint, and totalling the values across all servlets you would be able to tell when traffic has stopped.

10:17am

```
vendor_servlet_request_total{servlet=MyServletA} 100
vendor_servlet_request_total{servlet=MyServletB} 205
```

10:18am

```
vendor_servlet_request_total{servlet=MyServletA} 102
vendor_servlet_request_total{servlet=MyServletB} 209
```

10:19am

```
vendor_servlet_request_total{servlet=MyServletA} 102
vendor_servlet_request_total{servlet=MyServletB} 209
```

In the example above, since the servlet request counts didn't change between 10:18am and 10:19am you can conclude that the last access was before 10:18am.

see https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/general/#metrics-catalog.html for more detail on the available metrics from mpMetrics-2.x.

Comment: What you mean by labeled time series for each servlet.?

Comment: @user3410249, I updated my answer to be more clear about what a time series is and to show an example.

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a filter that would intercept all requests to the app and update variable that would hold last access , or return that variable value if you would query for that.